# How to integrate Google Cast v3 with ExoPlayer v2?

Tags: android, google-cast, exoplayer

How to fully integrate Google Cast v3 with ExoPlayer v2? The activity will contain a `FrameLayout` with a `com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView` in it. The [Google tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cast-videos-android) only covers integration with `VideoView`.

Answer (score 3):

The code below is available in a Kotlin class in this Gist that should help people trying to set up their CastPlayer for the first time:

https://gist.github.com/stefan-zh/fd52e0ee06088ac4086d2ea3fb7d7f3e

Also, going through this tutorial from Google will help you: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cast-videos-android/index.html#0

I also used this tutorial to get started: https://android.jlelse.eu/sending-media-to-chromecast-has-never-been-easier-c331eeef1e0a

---

Here is a breakdown how to achieve this using ExoPlayer and its Cast extension.

#### 1. You will need these dependencies:

```
// ExoPlayer is an advanced media player for playing media files
implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:$exoplayer_version"
implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:$exoplayer_version"
implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-cast:$exoplayer_version"
```

#### 2. You will need the Cast button

The Cast button can be added in the options menu for the activities. This is the recommended way to do it.

Add the following to `res/menu/browse.xml` (in my case the menu file is called `browse.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/media_route_menu_item"
        android:title="@string/media_route_menu_title"
        app:actionProviderClass="androidx.mediarouter.app.MediaRouteActionProvider"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

Then add the following code to your Activity to enable the `castButton`:

```
/**
 * We need to populate the Cast button across all activities as suggested by Google Cast Guide:
 * https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/design_checklist/cast-button#sender-cast-icon-available
 */
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
   val result = super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
   menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.browse, menu)
   castButton = CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(applicationContext, menu, R.id.media_route_menu_item)
   return result
}
```

#### 3. Declare your Options Provider for the Cast context

You need this so that you get the options dialog with the list of devices that you can cast to. Add this to your `AndroidManifest.xml` in the `application` tag:

```
<meta-data
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.OPTIONS_PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME"
   android:value="com.google.android.exoplayer2.ext.cast.DefaultCastOptionsProvider" />
```

#### 4. Your Activity needs to implement ExoPlayer's Cast Extension interface [`SessionAvailabilityListener`](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ext/cast/SessionAvailabilityListener.html)

This interface will allow you to listen for changes in the Cast session availability. Based on whether a Cast session is available you can direct playback to the local player or the remote player.

```
override fun onCastSessionAvailable() {
    playOnPlayer(castPlayer)
}

override fun onCastSessionUnavailable() {
    playOnPlayer(exoPlayer)
}
```

#### 5. You will need logic to initialize the players:

Notice how we are calling `castPlayer?.setSessionAvailabilityListener(this)` where `this` refers to your Activity that implements the `SessionAvailabilityListener` interface. The listener's methods will be called when the Cast session availability changes.

```
private fun initializePlayers() {
    exoPlayer = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build()
    playerView.player = exoPlayer

    if (castPlayer == null) {
        castPlayer = CastPlayer(castContext)
        castPlayer?.setSessionAvailabilityListener(this)
    }

    // start the playback
    if (castPlayer?.isCastSessionAvailable == true) {
        playOnPlayer(castPlayer)
    } else {
        playOnPlayer(exoPlayer)
    }
}
```

#### 6. You need logic to play on the selected player:

- This method allows you to store the playback state (`playbackPosition`, `playWhenReady`, or `windowIndex`)
- Create the correct media type for the local or remote players
- Select which player should start playback

playOnPlayer() method:

```
private fun playOnPlayer(player: Player?) {
    if (currentPlayer == player) {
        return
    }

    // save state from the existing player
    currentPlayer?.let {
        if (it.playbackState != Player.STATE_ENDED) {
            it.rememberState()
        }
        it.stop(true)
    }

    // set the new player
    currentPlayer = player

    // set up the playback
    // if the current player is the ExoPlayer, play from it
    if (currentPlayer == exoPlayer) {
        // build the MediaSource from the URI
        val uri = Uri.parse(videoClipUrl)
        val dataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(this@SampleCastingPlayerActivity, "exoplayer-agent")
        val mediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri)

        // use stored state (if any) to resume (or start) playback
        exoPlayer?.playWhenReady = playWhenReady
        exoPlayer?.seekTo(currentWindow, playbackPosition)
        exoPlayer?.prepare(mediaSource, false, false)
    }

    // if the current player is the CastPlayer, play from it
    if (currentPlayer == castPlayer) {
        val metadata = MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE)
        metadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, "Title")
        metadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_SUBTITLE, "Subtitle")
        metadata.addImage(WebImage(Uri.parse("any-image-url")))

        val mediaInfo = MediaInfo.Builder(videoClipUrl)
            .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
            .setContentType(MimeTypes.VIDEO_MP4)
            .setMetadata(metadata)
            .build()
        val mediaItem = MediaQueueItem.Builder(mediaInfo).build()
        castPlayer?.loadItem(mediaItem, playbackPosition)
    }
}
```

#### 7. Remember state and clean up resources

Each time you switch your application between background or foreground you would need to release or request resources. Each time you release the Player's resources back to the system you would need to save its state.

```
/**
 * Remembers the state of the playback of this Player.
 */
private fun Player.rememberState() {
    this@SampleCastingPlayerActivity.playWhenReady = playWhenReady
    this@SampleCastingPlayerActivity.playbackPosition = currentPosition
    this@SampleCastingPlayerActivity.currentWindow = currentWindowIndex
}

/**
 * Releases the resources of the local player back to the system.
 */
private fun releaseLocalPlayer() {
    exoPlayer?.release()
    exoPlayer = null
    playerView.player = null
}

/**
 * Releases the resources of the remote player back to the system.
 */
private fun releaseRemotePlayer() {
    castPlayer?.setSessionAvailabilityListener(null)
    castPlayer?.release()
    castPlayer = null
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to change DefaultCastOptionsProvider? I tried to add cast MiniControllerFragment to the app and when i tap on it the ExpandedControllerActivity does not open as it should.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can write your own class that extends `OptionsProvider` and override `getCastOptions(context: Context?): CastOptions` and `getAdditionalSessionProviders(context: Context?): MutableList<SessionProvider>`. Then you will use the fully qualified name for this class in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Google Cast SDK is independent of Local Player, you can use `ExoPlayer` or `MediaPlayer` ( `VideoView` )

Once your APP has an active session, place the url in `MediaInfo`

```
val movieMetadata = MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE)

movieMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, "Title")
movieMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_SUBTITLE, "Sub")

val mediaLoadOptions =  MediaInfo.Builder( < URL > )
     .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
     .setContentType(< Content Type of Media>)
     .setMetadata(movieMetadata)
     .setStreamDuration(<Media Duration >)
     .build()

mCastSession.remoteMediaClient.load(buildMediaInfo(url), mediaLoadOptions)
```

If you need to stream a local media, you will need to stream it for yourself, using [NanoHttpd](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd) or another of your choice, and also implement a [Cast Receiver](https://github.com/googlecast/CastReferencePlayer)